# How to Hide and then Show on Click Multiple Content Items by Default?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code. By default it shows, but I want to hide it by default.

Also, I'm unable to control both of the divs, only 1 of the show/hide toggles work, I want for them (but have been unsuccessful) both to work.

How can I hide by default and expand on click?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>

<br><br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it 2</button>

<div id="myDIV2">
This is my DIV element.
</div>

<p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV2");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var x = document.getElementById("myDIV2");
```

You are overwriting your `x` variable.
Assign `myDIV2` to another variable like `y` and repeat the process.

Better would be to just assign the same `class` instead of `id` to the elements you want to hide and just toggle the class instead of trying to get each element by id.

https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/javascript-hasclass-addclass-removeclass-toggleclass

Answer (score 0):

Just separate the function on the first and scond button

```js
function myFunction_1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  var y = document.getElementById("myDIV2");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function myFunction_2() {
  var y = document.getElementById("myDIV2");
  if (y.style.display === "none") {
    y.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    y.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>
<button onclick="myFunction_1()">Try it</button>
<div id="myDIV">
  This is my DIV element.
</div>
<br><br>
<button onclick="myFunction_2()">Try it 2</button>
<div id="myDIV2">
  This is my DIV element.
</div>
<p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>
```

Comment: what do you mean *by default?* you want one to collapse another